# How to comment on receiving a game request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-games

I have just received a game request from a friend and wanted to comment on it, but do not find any way to do it.

Clicking on the request leads to opening of the app.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot comment on game requests on Facebook.